# adding two numeric values results null value in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In a stored procedure I am trying to add two numeric values as shown

```
DECLARE @tradeamt1 NUMERIC(23,2)

DECLARE @tradeamt3 NUMERIC(23,2)

DECLARE @value NUMERIC(23,2)

if (@retVal1 = 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT  @row_count = count(1), 
    @tradeamt1=Sum(trade_amt) ,
    @units= Sum(curr_shrs_num) 
FROM [csr_staging].[dbo].[fi_impact_source] WITH(NOLOCK) 
Where acct_id = 'BANKFEES'
and SD_ID >= EFF_DT 
print @tradeamt1
END

if(@retVal3 > 0)
BEGIN


select @row_count = count(1) - @retVal3 + @row_count,@tradeamt3=Sum(trade_amt),@units= @units +Sum(curr_shrs_num) - @currshares
FROM [CSR_Staging].[dbo].[fi_impact_source]  WITH(NOLOCK) 
where (clearing_code = 'MBS'or clearing_code = 'CNS') and (SD_ID >= EFF_DT)

print @tradeamt3

END

set @value = @tradeamt1 +@tradeamt3
```

this value gives null instead of adding tradeamount1 =1.00 and tradeamount3 = 191432650.13

Comment: How you want us to help here? We don't know what is on the table or what are the values of those variables.  Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: So `tradeamount1` and `tradeamount3` already have values but `set @value = @tradeamt1 +@tradeamt3` return null?

Comment: yes tradeamt1= 1.00 and tradeamt3 = 191432650.13

Comment: That doesn't sound right. You need do some debugging to found where is the problem. You should start with some basic statements you know work like [**this**](https://rextester.com/MLYPZL12119) and then start adding statements until you found what break it.

Comment: i am using print statement and when i run it is displays the values correctly but not when i add the two numbers ie  (tradeamt1 + tradeamt3)

Comment: As I said there is no way we could test that, as you saw in my link works ok. Start with a simple working scenario and add some statements one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this could work for your SP:

```
declare   @tradeamt1 numeric(23, 2) = 0
        , @tradeamt3 numeric(23, 2) = 0
        , @value numeric(23, 2) = 0

select @row_count = 0, @units = 0

if @retVal1 = 0
    select @row_count = count(1)
        ,  @tradeamt1 = isnull(sum(trade_amt), 0)
        ,  @units     = isnull(sum(curr_shrs_num), 0)
    from [CSR_Staging].[dbo].[fi_impact_source] with (nolock)
    where acct_id = 'BANKFEES'
        and SD_ID >= EFF_DT

if @retVal3 > 0
    select @row_count = @row_count + count(1) - @retVal3
        ,  @tradeamt3 = isnull(sum(trade_amt), 0)
        ,  @units     = @units + isnull(sum(curr_shrs_num), 0) - @currshares
    from [CSR_Staging].[dbo].[fi_impact_source] with (nolock)
    where clearing_code in ('MBS', 'CNS')
        and SD_ID >= EFF_DT

set @value = @tradeamt1 + @tradeamt3
```

Using `isNull(` ensures that both `@tradeamt1` and `@tradeamt3` are not null

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably because when tradeamt1 and tradeamt3 are not initialised and for some reason also not assigned values.

You could initialise them with:

```
DECLARE @tradeamt1 NUMERIC(23,2) = 0

DECLARE @tradeamt3 NUMERIC(23,2) = 0

DECLARE @value NUMERIC(23,2) = 0
```

Let me know if that helps.

:)

Comment: it is returning 0 instead of adding the two numbers

Comment: I think what Juan Carlos is saying in the comments of your question is right. There's no real way for us to test it out. What I'd suggest is you remove the if statements, just assign the values regardless and see if you get the numbers to add up.

Comment: sure ill try that